# meaning of "ebenda"

Tags: meaning

Collins and Oxford say *ebenda* means *ibid*. Duden has an additional meaning: *exactly*.

None of these makes sense when you frequently see the use of *ebenda* next to dates, for example in [this Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albrecht_Graf_von_Bernstorff):

> Albrecht Theodor Andreas Graf von Bernstorff (* 6. März 1890 in
>   Berlin; † vermutlich 23. oder 24. April 1945 **ebenda**)

So what does it actually mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are misreading what [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ebenda) wrote. It's not

> (genau) oder (gerade dort)

but

> (genau oder gerade) dort

The meaning is indeed equal to Latin

> *ibidem*: am selben Ort

A slightly outdated synonym for *ebenda* is

> daselbst [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/daselbst) [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ebenda)

In the context you quoted, *ebenda* means that he died at the same place he was born, i.e. Berlin.

Comment: Good observation of the misreading.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already tried two dictionaries, [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=ebenda) actually provides an answer. As a native speaker, I never heard the word before, although I could guess from context, so I'd argue it's rather unusual in everyday language. However it appears to be used in scientific context or in earlier books, where saving space was essential.

Here it means

> at the same place

Comment: I would not say that it is unusual as such, but reserved to certain contexts. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebenda

Comment: It is even pretty usual - in the specific context of scientific papers written in German. There it is used to refer to an earlier citation. It is often abbreviated to *ebd.*

Comment: In printed reference works saving the space was essential; Brockhaus Konversationslexikon 1894-1896 alone has more than 6600 occurrences.